# Java Generics - Accept Specific Type of Object

Tags: java, object, generics, serialization

I have a class that has a field of getting `Serializers`. One which is `valueSelializer` that will accept a Serializer class which has a SpecificRecordBase as its arguments and a `keySerializer` that will accept serializers such as `StringSerializer`, `IntegerSerializer` (with not Generic object as their arguments) etc.

Current implementation is

```java
@Builder
@Data
public class FactoryProperties<T extends SpecificRecordBase> {

    private Serializer<?> keySerializer;

    private Serializer<T> valueSerializer;
}
```

```java
public <T extends SpecificRecordBase> FactoryPropertiesBuilder<T> defaultProducerBuilderProperties(
        Class<T> targetType) {
            return FactoryProperties.<T>builder()
                .keySerializer(new StringSerializer())
                .valueSerializer(new AvroSerializer<T>());
    }
```

Question is if I wont use wildcard `<?>`, how can I specify the objects that can be accepted on `keySerializer`

I initially tried this one

```java
@Builder
@Data
public class FactoryProperties<S extends Object, T extends SpecificRecordBase> {

    private Serializer<S> keySerializer;

    private Serializer<T> valueSerializer;
}
```

```java
public <S extends Object, T extends SpecificRecordBase> FactoryPropertiesBuilder<S, T> defaultProducerBuilderProperties(
        Class<T> targetType) {
            return FactoryProperties.<S,T>builder()
                .keySerializer(new StringSerializer())
                .valueSerializer(new AvroSerializer<T>());
    }
```

But having an error when trying to initialize the value of `keySerializer`

> The method keySerializer(Serializer) in the type FactoryProperties.FactoryPropertiesBuilder<S,T> is not applicable for the arguments (StringSerializer)

These are some of the objects that can be accepted `String` (StringSerializer<String), `Integer` (IntegerSerializer) and `Byte[]` (ByteArraySerializer<byte[]>)

Would really appreciate if someone help me to understand whats wrong, been stuck here for some hours. Thanks

Answer (score 0):

```
public <S extends Object, T extends SpecificRecordBase> FactoryPropertiesBuilder<S, T> defaultProducerBuilderProperties(Class<T> targetType) {
            return FactoryProperties.<S,T>builder()
                 .keySerializer(new StringSerializer())
```

Here is what the compiler is thinking:

We are passing a `StringSerializer`, which implements `Serializer<String>`, to a method that requires a `Serializer<S>`. This is valid if and only if `S` is `String`.

The type `S` is specified by the caller of `defaultProducerBuilderProperties()`, and required to `extend Object`. For instance, `S` could be `Number`, because `Number extends Object`.

It's not ok to pass a `Serializer<String>` where a `Serializer<Number>` is expected. For instance, if somebody calls:

```
FactoryPropertiesBuilder<Number, T> builder = defaultProducerPropertiesBuilder(tClass);
```

they expect getting a `NumberSerializer`, but your code gives them a `StringSerializer`. That's not the correct type.

Comment: hi appreciate it. so what I should do is just to stick with using wildcard `<?>` ? thanks

Comment: The compiler says the declared type of `defaultProducerPropertiesBuilder` doesn't match its implementation. I don't know whether the declared type or the implementation are correct. If the caller should decide which Serializer is constructed, it will have to tell `defaultProducerBuilderPorperties`, probably by passing a parameter. If it's always a `StringSerializer`, your return type should say so, i.e. you would declare `public <T extends SpecificRecordBase> FactoryPropertiesBuilder<String, T> defaultProcuderBuilderProperties`.